# Delete button not returning correct values to delete query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table which displays data drawn from 2 different tables in mysql.The table has a delete button on each row which, when pressed, would send run a delete query which would delete the row, and all it's associated data from the database.

However,no matter which delete button i click, it is always the last row in the table that is deleted, and not the row which the delete button is in.

My table:

```
-------------------------------------------
|Username|Password|Branch Name|Branch Info|
----------------------------------------------------
|Sub1    |Pass1   |branch1    |1st branch |DELETE  |
----------------------------------------------------
|Sub2    |Pass2   |branch2    |2nd branch |DELETE  |<---this button is pressed
----------------------------------------------------
|Sub3    |Pass3   |branch3    |3rd branch |DELETE  |
----------------------------------------------------
|Sub4    |Pass4   |branch4    |4th branch |DELETE  |
----------------------------------------------------
|Sub5    |Pass5   |branch5    |5th branch |DELETE  |<---this row is deleted.
----------------------------------------------------
```

My code:

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if(@$_SESSION['Auth']!=="Yes" AND @$_SESSION['Type']!=="Admin")
{
echo"You are not authorised to view this page.Please click <a href='Login.php'>here</a> to login.";
exit();
}
?>

<?PHP

if(@$_POST['deluser']=="Delete")
{
include("cxn.inc");
print_r($_POST);
$id="$_POST[id]";
echo"$id";
if(empty($_POST["id"]))
echo"yep";
$deluser="DELETE FROM SubUsers WHERE SubUsers.id='$id'";
$delquery=mysqli_query($cxn,$deluser) or die (mysqli_error($cxn));
$delsuccess="Deletion successful";
}
>

<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head>
<body>


<?PHP
include("cxn.inc");
//include("AdminNav.php");
$viewuser="SELECT SubUsers.Id,Username,Password,Name,Info FROM SubUsers,Branch WHERE SubUsers.id=Branch.id AND SubUsers.Userid='$_SESSION[UserId]'";
$runuser=mysqli_query($cxn,$viewuser) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$rows=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runuser))
$rows[]=$row;
echo"<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' name='DelUser' method='POST' >";
echo"<table border='1'>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Username";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Password";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Branch Name";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Branch Info";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
foreach($rows as $row)
{
$id=$row['Id'];
echo"$id";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Username]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Password]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Name]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Info]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' >";
echo"<input type='Submit' name='deluser' value='Delete' >";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td colspan='5'>";
if(isset($delsuccess))
{echo"$delsuccess";}

echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The line

echo"$id";

under the foreach loop successfully returns the id of each row correctly as each row is being output to the screen.

Upon pressing the DELETE Button, the line

```
print_r($_POST);
```

outputs all variables in $_POST, which gives the result

```
Array ( [id] => x [deluser] => Delete )
```

where x is the id of the last row in the table(E.g if there are 5 rows in the table, x=5)

***QUESTION***
Why does the DELETE button keep passing the id of the last row only, and not the id of the row it's on?Also, how and what do i have to do to make it so that when the delete button is pressed, only the row beside the delete button is deleted?

I've been looking at this for the past 2 hours and still can't figure out where i'm wrong; the code is obviously working as rows are being deleted when the delete buton is pressed, however it's just that the WRONG rows are being deleted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: where is the rest of the html(buttons)

Comment: @Gunr Jesra what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close your form, so the last value assigned to ID is used.

Each Delete button needs to be a seperate form

Also please note that echo can use multiple lines

```
//Remove start of form from here.
echo"<table border='1'>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Username";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Password";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Branch Name";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"Branch Info";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
foreach($rows as $row)
{
$id=$row['Id'];
echo"$id";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Username]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Password]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Name]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Info]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
    //form isnt needed till here.
    echo"<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' name='DelUser' method='POST' >";
echo"<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' >";
    //Line below has changed.
echo"<input type='Submit' name='deluser' value='Delete' ></form>";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td colspan='5'>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Toby, it's working now.

Just a quick question though, Why does each delete button have to be a separate form? Or rather, why must each Submit button be in a separate form of each own? i was under the impression that i could have multiple submit buttons in a form in PHP as i have a registration form that has multiple input fields, albeit only one submit button.

Comment: @Ken I explained it in my answer

Comment: That's the way HTML forms work.  You can absolutly have multiple submit buttons and multiple ID values but they will all be submitted so you will need to link your submit form that is clicked with your id, you need unique IDs.  Much easier to have seperate forms.

Answer (score 1):

Submit button sends whole form, not just nearest input. So you are sending every id from your table and value of pressed button. Since every hidden input has some name, variable in `$_POST` is being overwritten and is equal to the last value.

You have either make separate forms for each row to make sure only only one `id` is send (that may make your html bigger), or resign from hidden input and change your delete button name to include desired id:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='deluser[$id]' value='Delete'>";
```

With this, your post will look like:

```
$_POST['deluser'] = array(7 => 'Delete');
```

Only value from pressed button will be send. You can easily access this id in php:

```
if (isset($_POST['deluser'])) {
    $id_to_delete = key($_POST['deluser']);
}
```

If you are not concerned about users with very IE version, you can use `button` element instead of submit:

```
echo "<button type='submit' name='deluser' value='$id'>Delete</button>";
```

With this, id will be accessible simply by `$_POST['deluser']`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you will have n (n being number of records) declarations on the hidden field id. This will probably only take the last one. So to get this working, you need to make sure the correct hidden field is selected.

Either add this to the delete function, of create fields with the id incorperated.

Answer (score 0):

you have one form for all id's

```
<?PHP
include("cxn.inc");
//include("AdminNav.php");

?>


<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Branch Name</td>
<td>Branch Info</td>
</tr>


<?php
$viewuser="SELECT SubUsers.Id,Username,Password,Name,Info FROM SubUsers,Branch WHERE SubUsers.id=Branch.id AND SubUsers.Userid='$_SESSION[UserId]'";
$runuser=mysqli_query($cxn,$viewuser) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runuser)){
$id=$row['Id'];

echo"<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' name='DelUser' method='POST' >";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Username]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Password]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Name]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"$row[Info]";
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo"<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' >";
echo"<input type='Submit' name='deluser' value='Delete' >";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"</form>";
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td colspan='5'>";
if(isset($delsuccess))
{echo"$delsuccess";}
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete according to selected id, which will resolve your problem. For example,if you want to delete sub2, it will have id in db. For example:-

```
<form name="form3" id="form3" action="delete_xyz.php" method="get" onsubmit="return check();">
      <input type="image" src="../images/delete.png" type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete"  title="Deletes Selected Product" style="cursor:pointer" />
      <input type="hidden" name="delete" id="delete"  value="<?php echo $row['Complain_id']; ?>"/>
</form>
```